# Getting image from Core Data

Tags: ios, swift, image, core-data, nsdata

I'm working on a Cocktailapp and want to save my image data to Core Data.
I watched some tutorials and did the same but it's still not working an I don't know why.

I have an Array with all titles for the images:

```
let imagesAperitif: [String] = ["americano.jpg", "daiquiri.jpg",
        "frozen daiquiri.jpg",
        "banana frozen daiquiri.jpg", "bronx.jpg", "kir.jpg",
        "hugo.jpg", "Manhattann.jpg", "manhattan dry.jpg", "manhattan medium.jpg", "margarita.jpg",
        "martini dry.jpg",...
```

Thats where I call my method for saving the images to Core Data:

```
setCocktails(nameInsert, zutaten: zutatenInsert, zubereitung: zubereitungInsert, dekoration: dekorationInsert, stil: stilInsert, bild: UIImage(named: imagesAperitif[index])!)
```

That's a part from the code of saveCocktails method:

```
let imageData = NSData(data: UIImageJPEGRepresentation(bild, 1.0)!)
eintrag.setValue(imageData, forKey: "bild")

do {
    try managedContext.save()
```

That's part of the fetching method:

```
let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Cocktail")

do {
    let results =
    try managedContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest)
    cocktails = results as! [NSManagedObject]
```

And here I want to get my image back from NSData:

```
imagesAperitif.append(UIImage(data: eintrag.valueForKey("bild") as! NSData)!)
```

But the App crashes with this line and I get a "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" error.

Is anybody able to explain this to me because I don't know what to change. Everything I tried went also wrong.

Comment: try printing the value read from coredata.App Crashes because its not able to create the uiimage object.

Comment: Slightly confusing for the non-english namings. :(. You may want to check whether `UIImage(data: eintrag.valueForKey("bild") as! NSData)` is correctly initialised.

Comment: @AnilSanto what do you mean with printing the value?

Comment: @zcui93 Sorry I'm from Germany so the german naming :D
But they are correct, otherwise the error would be different

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check `nil` for `eintrag.valueForKey("bild")` before case it to `NSData`

As 
    func valueForKey(_ key: String) -> AnyObject?

And it's always save to check `nil` before you append `UIImage(data: eintrag.valueForKey("bild") as! NSData)`

Comment: But that doesn't solve my problem because there has to be an image

Comment: You are writing your code, saying that your cast to NSData will always succeed, but it doesn't obviously. One of the values you are using is nil. That is why it's crashing. Using the "!" disables xcode asking you to check for nil, but the value may still be nil. So what zcui93 is trying to tell you, is you should check if your required values are nil.

Either eintrag.valueForKey("bild") has no value, or your cast to NSData fails or the UIImage object is nil.

Comment: I know that one value has to be nil at the moment but I don't know why, that's why I posted my question

Comment: Well could you tell us what value is nil then? Is eintrag.valueForKey("bild") nil? Does your entity have a property named "bild"? You can actually cast your NSManagedObject to the class you use in the core data designer. This would enable you to use: eintrag.bild instead of eintrag.valueForKey("bild").

Comment: Yes, eintrag.valueForKey("bild") is nil. And yes, the entity has a property named "bild".
I'm doing the same thing with other properties and everything works fine, so I'm thinking that the cast from UIImage to NSData went wrong or gets a nil, but I don't know how to check whether the cast is true or not

Comment: You can check if a cast fails or succeeds by putting it in either a guard or if statement. See my post below.

Comment: @PhilippRosengart  The way you convert `UIImage` to `NSData` is fine. But it's still safer to check whether you inserted nil to Core Data before.

Answer (score 0):

(I like using guard so here goes :) )

So what I would do here since it looks like the inserting of the NSData object fails:

```
// We are simultaniously unwrapping objects and checking if objects are nil.
guard let imgAsNSData: NSData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(bild, 1.0),
    let entity: Cocktail = eintrag as? Cocktail else {
        // Stop executing the method here, there is no point in going further. Handle any errors here! Either imgAsNSData is nil, or could not cast to your class. A guard statement handles it's errors here.
        return
}

// At this point we know we have an NSData object. Assign it to the entity.
entity.bild = imgAsNSData

do {
    // Save our entity.
    try managedContext.save()
} catch {
    // Handle error
}
```

Fetching:

```
let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Cocktail")

do {
    let results: [NSManagedObject] = try managedContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest)
guard let cocktails = results as? [Cocktail] else {
    // Could not cast to an array of Cocktail objects.
    return
}

// Do stuff with the cocktails object.
```

Add to your array:

```
// 1: Check if entity not is nil
// 2: Check if entity's bild property not is nil.
// 3: Check if we can create an image using the NSData
guard let cocktail: Cocktail = eintrag as? Cocktail,
    let imgAsNSData: NSData = cocktail.bild,
    let image: UIImage = UIImage(data: imgAsNSData) else {
        // Required values are nil. Cannot proceed.
        return
}

imagesAperitif.append(image)
```

Untested code so be careful :)

Comment: Allright, I had some trouble with your code and it's still don't working everything, but I tested the guard statement, both at saving the image an getting the image back from NSData, and both guard statements seems to be truth, the else block doesn't get into action. But appending the image still get's the nil error

Comment: So isn't imagesAperitif nil then?

Comment: guard let imageData: UIImage = UIImage(data: eintrag.valueForKey("bild") as! NSData)
                else
                {
                    return
                }
                
                imagesAperitif.append(imageData)

I tested it with this statement because it was the only way I got it working, and the guar statement don't went to the else block, but appending get's still the error

Comment: I get that but the image does not have to be the only value that's nil. I think imagesAperitif is nil. You probably defined it as var imagesAperitif: [UIImage]!.

Comment: Thats it, thanks man :))
I declared the array as var imagesAperitif: [UIImage]!
It's working now...So many posts and such a stupid error

Comment: I've done my fair share of checking what values are nil. I'm very careful with writing my code now and try to avoid the usage of "!" like the plague. I'd rather check every value for nil values. I'd like to think it'd make for safer code. Good luck with future sigabrt's :)